# Use the option menu in THEME style but using THEME.HOLO.LIGHT

Tags: android, themes

As the title, is possible to use the style of menu standard of android:Theme but in `android:Theme.Holo.Light`?

Just the menu when I click the menu button. The THEME menu are horizontal and with icon but the `THEME.HOLO.LIGHT` is vertical and without icon.

Thanks.

Comment: Many devices do not have a MENU button, including all devices that ship with Android 4.4 or higher.

Comment: Then what's your suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion is that you leave the overflow menu alone.